# Are there USB powered speakers with an Analog port?

Tags: audio, power-supply, power, usb-power

I have built a raspberry Pi Jukebox, specially modified for a handicapped user (voice feedback on all songs, large buttons) but I have one.... last.... problem.

The speakers I used ran off the analog port, which is fun.  Alas, they had to be plugged into the wall - and I decided to make this portable for the guy.  I wish to power the device as a whole using one of [these babies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009V5X1CE).  However, the speakers a 12 volts.

I actually own some of these guys: 
[image]
Any help there?  Thanks!

Comment: If portability is a design goal wouldn't headphones be a better alternative and not require external power?

Comment: The design goal is really to allow either... he's a very social kid... he might like to let it fill a room...

Comment: What about a Bluetooth speaker(s)?

Comment: Hmmm... because he is blind, I'd kinda like to embed the speakers, so the ranged aspect seems unnecessary, but I suppose it would actually work...

Comment: I have used speakers that are powered via USB but take input via headphone jack but I don't have a link for you.

Comment: Here's a set that is powered from USB - http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/product/stereo-speakers-z120

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a set that is powered from USB - http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/product/stereo-speakers-z120